# How To prove Any Change to $v=a\cdot y + b$ maks $y=(a)^{-1}(v-b)$ Uni. random value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, finite-fields, uniform-distribution

This question may seem to be related to [Probability and Data Integrity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423060/probability-and-data-integrity) but mine is much simpler and consideres a DIFFERENT problem.

Let a finite field be $\mathbb{Z}_p$, where $p$ is a prime number.

I have a fixed value $y_i$ and two uniformly random values $a_i$ and $b_i$.

---

I compute $v_i=a_i\cdot y_i + b_i$, and send it to the server. The server can do **any** change to $v_i$. Assume that I can magically detect if $y_i$ becomes a uniformly random value (see below how it might be possible)

I can download $v_i$ and remove the random valus to obtain $y_i$

---

**Question:** How can I prove that **any** change to $v_i$ makes $y_i$ a uniformly random value?

---

Imagine we have a polynopmial $P(x)=(x-\beta)\cdot g(x)$ define over the field. Then evaluate $P(x)$ at $n$ number of $x_i$'s. This gives us $y_i$'s. So if any subset of $y_i$ is replaced with a set of uniformly random values, with a high probability we cannot retrieve $\beta$ as a root of interpolating polynomial.

TBN: $a_i,b_i,y_i\neq0$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is $v=\ (r_i)^{-1}\cdot z $, a uniformly random value of a field?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423174/is-v-r-i-1-cdot-z-a-uniformly-random-value-of-a-field)

Comment: @MorganRodgers Here the random elements are be picked uniformly at random from the field with no contrains.

Comment: This is also essentially identical to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409437/is-ar-cdot-b-an-uniformly-random-value-when-a-b-are-fixed-and-r-is-rando?rq=1

Comment: @MorganRodgers How to show ANY change can make $y_i$ a uniformly random value is  Exactly what I would like to know.

Comment: @MorganRodgers   The question above is DIFFERENET from those you mentioned.

Comment: Why the subscripts? And what happens if $a_i =0$?
And by any changes, can I raise $v_i$ to a power? Can I compute $x^{v_i}$?

Comment: @Hetebrij "Why the subscripts?": I used subscripts in the last paragraph to explain how I can detect if $y_i$'s are changed to a uni. randm values. Actually subscript are NOT needed for the question.   " what happens if $a_i=0$?" ALL values are non-zero ."can I raise vi to a power? Can I compute $x^{v_i}$?": YES.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first drop the subscripts, and let $z= a^{-1} \left( f ( a y + b) - b \right)$, where $f : \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_p$ is any change the computer makes to $ay+b$.
Then we want to show that given any $f$, $z$ is uniform distributed. Unfortunately, this is not true in general.

If you want a counterexample in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for any $p$, we take $f$ to be the indicator of $\{0\}$, and then we have, we assume $a$ and $b$ independent,
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(z=0) &=& \mathbb{P}( a^{-1} ( f(ay+b) - b) = 0 ) \\
&=& \mathbb{P}(f(ay+b) -b = 0) \\
&=& \mathbb{P}(f(ay+b) = b) \\
&=& \mathbb{P}(f(ay+b) = 1 \textrm{ and } b=1) \\
&=& \mathbb{P}(a = -y^{-1} \textrm{ and } b=1 )\\
&=& \mathbb{P}(a = - y^{-1}) \mathbb{P}(b=1) \\
&=& \frac{1}{(p-1)^2}
\end{eqnarray}
So for $z$ to be uniform, we must at least have $(p-1)^2$ elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, which clearly is not possible for $p>2$.

---

If we have that $z \neq 0$, we have the constraint $ f(ay+b) - b \neq 0$.
We will show that this yields quite a constraint on the allowed functions $f$, and that for only one function this yields $z \in U(1,p-1)$ when $p>2$.

Let $y \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ be fixed and non-zero. Since $a$ is uniform and non-zero, we have that $ay \in \mathbb{Z}_p \backslash \{0\}$, where every element has a chance of $\frac{1}{p-1}$.
So given $v=ay+b$, we can find for all $\tilde{b} \in \mathbb{Z}_p \backslash \{ 0, v \}$ a $\tilde{a} \in \mathbb{Z}_p \backslash \{0\}$ such that $\tilde{a}+\tilde{b} = v$.
So if the computer knows $v$, it can only know that $b \neq v$, since $b \neq 0$.
So we must have $f(x) \in \{0,x\}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$.

If we have $v_i \in \mathbb{Z}_p \backslash \{0\}$ such that $f(v_i) = v_i$ for $i=1,\dots,k$ we find
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(ay+b = v_i) &=& \sum_{\tilde{b} \not\in \{0,v_i\} }\mathbb{P}(b = \tilde{b}) \mathbb{P}(a = y^{-1} ( v_i - \tilde{b})) \\
&=& \sum_{\tilde{b} \not\in \{0,v_i\}} \frac{1}{p-1} \frac{1}{p-1} \\
&=& \frac{1}{p-1} -\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}
\end{eqnarray}
For $ay+b = v_i$ we have $z=a^{-1}( f(ay+b) -b) = a^{-1}( ay+b - b)=y$. So we find
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(z=y) &\ge& \sum_{i=1}^k \mathbb{P}(ay+b = v_i) \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{p-1} - \frac{1}{(p-1)^2}\\
&=& \frac{k}{p-1} -\frac{k}{(p-1)^2}
\end{eqnarray}
And for $k\ge 2$ we have that this is strictly greater than $\frac{1}{p-1}$, so $z$ is not uniform.

So assume there exists $v \in \mathbb{Z}_p \backslash \{0\}$ such that $f(v)=v$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x \neq v$.
Then we have $\mathbb{P}(ay+b=v) = \frac{1}{p-1}-\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}$.
Furthermore, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(- a^{-1}b=y) &=& \mathbb{P}(b = -ay ) \\
&=& \sum_{\tilde{a} \neq 0} \mathbb{P}(b = -\tilde{a}y ) \mathbb{P}(a = \tilde{a} ) \\
&=& \sum_{\tilde{a} \neq 0} \frac{1}{p-1} \frac{1}{p-1} \\
&=& \frac{1}{p-1}
\end{eqnarray}
We note that $-a^{-1}b=y$ implies $ay +b = ay -ay =0 \neq v$.
So we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(z=y) &=& \mathbb{P}(ay+b =v) + \mathbb{P}(-a^{-1} b =y)\\
&=& \frac{1}{p-1} - \frac{1}{(p-1)^2} +\frac{1}{p-1}\\
&=& \frac{2}{p-1} - \frac{1}{(p-1)^2}\\
&>& \frac{1}{p-1}
\end{eqnarray}
So we again have that $z$ is not uniform.

Thus the only remaining possible function is $f = 0$. This gives for $v \in \mathbb{Z}_p \backslash \{0\}$
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(z =v ) &=& \mathbb{P}( -a^{-1}b = v) \\
&=& \sum_{\tilde{a} \neq 0 } \mathbb{P}(a = \tilde{a} ) \mathbb{P}(b = -v\tilde{a})\\
&=& \frac{1}{p-1}
\end{eqnarray}
So we have $z$ is uniform.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126141/discussion-on-answer-by-hetebrij-how-to-prove-any-change-to-va-cdot-y-b-mak).