# How does any function of a masked value change its distribution?

Tags: probability, group-theory, number-theory, probability-distributions, finite-fields

My question is related to information security, in particular data integrity.

---

Consider a client has a fixed value $y$ and two uniformly random values $a$ and $b$. It computes $v=a\cdot y+b$. Note the value $a,y,v\neq 0$  and  all the values are defined over a finite field $\mathbb{F}^*_p$, for a large prime number $p$ (512-bit).

The client sends $v$ to the server. The server can apply ANY change to $v$. In fact it computes any function of $v$, $f(v)$.
The client downloads $f(v)$ and then computes $y'=(a)^{-1}(f(v)-b)$

**Question 1:** Would this make $y'$ a uniformly random?

Or

**Question 2:** How does this change affect the distribution of $y'$?

---

I need to mention that a very close question was asked here. I do appreciate the answerer effort to answer that question; but I'm still not convinced with the answer: [How To prove Any Change to $v=a\cdot y + b$ maks $y=(a)^{-1}(v-b)$ Uni. random value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424328/how-to-prove-any-change-to-v-a-cdot-y-b-maks-y-a-1v-b-uni-random-v)

Comment: so are they uniformly sampled, or non-zero?

Comment: @Ilya $a$ must be non-zero uniformly random value. So its probability is $\frac{1}{p-1}$. In contrast $b$ is a uniformly random value and can be 0.

Comment: still, $v$ can easily be $0$

Comment: @Ilya See the client picks $a, b$ for its fixed value $y$. So it can construct a non-zero $v$. It needs value $y$ after he downloads it.

Comment: so he picks them, or they are drawn randomly (uniformly)

Comment: @Ilya In my "main protocol" and in many cryptocraphic protocols, the random values that are used to "blind" a fixed value, are picked uniformly random by the client, but they should be non-zero. The same is true for many probablistic encryption.

Comment: @Ilya I have eddited $\mathbb{F}_p$ to $\mathbb{F}^*_p$.

Comment: @Ilya Is $v=a\cdot y+b$ a uniformly random value where $a,b$ are uniforly random elemeents of the field and $y$ is fixed?

Comment: Yes, case $a = 0$ is obvious. If $a\neq 0$ then $ay$ is uniform (since $a$ is invertible), and the sum of two uniform independent is uniform (just gives shifted cycles with the same mass for all points).

Comment: @Ilya Thank you, I thought so. I'm just quoting anothers answer: "$a\cdot y+b$ is not uniform, since $a\cdot y+b$ can attain p values with $(p−1)^2$ different combinations of the $a$ and $b$, as calculated. If you are not convinced, try it out with $p=7$".

Comment: @Ilya http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424328/how-to-prove-any-change-to-v-a-cdot-y-b-maks-y-a-1v-b-uni-random-v/1425177?noredirect=1#comment2906220_1425177

Comment: why is it $(p-1)^2$? again, when I say uniform I mean over $[0;p-1]$, not over $[1; p-1]$

Comment: @Ilya I'm getting confused; why it is uniformly random in [0,p-1], but not in [1,p-1]?

Comment: I mean that my answer was assuming that $a$ and $b$ are uniformly distributed over $\Bbb F_p$, so including zero. In case at least one of them has different distribution, I agree with the comment of Hetebrij in your link.

Comment: @Ilya Thank you. See if I define both $a,b$ and $y$ over $[1,p-1]$, then $a,b$ can be uniformly random value. Would still $v=ay+b$ be distributed non-uniformly in $[1,p-1]$?

Comment: To start with, $v$ can take $0$ value, what do you think about it?

Comment: @Ilya It means I cannot use all possible $b,a$ values. Therefore they cannot be picked uni. random, because I need to exclude some of them